# How can a poor RNG impact security?

Tags: random-number-generator, entropy

I have read [this article](http://www.design-reuse.com/articles/27050/true-randomness-in-cryptography.html) and I do **somehow** "understand" that the reduction of entropy makes it easier to guess.

But how exactly can the security be reduced by that? Can you give a concrete scenario, where a poor (P)RNG leads to security issues?

Comment: would a sample from "recent" history suffice (aka Debian OpenSSL bug)?

Comment: You are not talking about "Heartbleed", are you? If it is caused by a poor RNG, I'd love to hear more. (edit: seems not to bee heartbleed, though never heard of it, thanks)

Comment: No, heartbleed was a "regular" bug in the OpenSSL library, the Debian OpenSSL bug was a flaw in Debian's OpenSSL version

Comment: Obligatory [XKCD](https://xkcd.com/221/). This happens a lot, in a form or another, e.g. [this](https://smartfacts.cr.yp.to/).

Comment: What happens if you "randomly" set the combination on your luggage to 0 0 0 0 0?

Comment: watch the video "how i met your girlfriend" for an easy to digest illustration. but just know that security is about secrets, and we usually assume random to be secret, so if it's not, then our assumptions go out the window and attackers can forge session cookies, break tls, and guess your RSA factors.

Comment: @MattNordhoff What do you mean? What happens? Sure by intuition I see that it is quite insecure. But why is this mathematically less secure than any other of the 10^5 possible combinations?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Suppose that you generate a brand new RSA key pair, that you will use, say, to authenticate yourself when connecting to a SSH server. This will be done through some library that implements RSA key pair generation (say, OpenSSL). That library will produce the key elements by generating random integers of the right length until such integers appear to be prime number.

The random generation uses a seed obtained from "true randomness" and then expanded into an arbitrarily long sequence of random bits with a [cryptographically secure PRNG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographically_secure_pseudorandom_number_generator). The point is to make it infeasible for an attacker to predict the bits you came up with.

Now suppose that the seed is of low entropy (e.g. 40 bits) or the PRNG is poorly designed and reduces the entropy. Saying "40 bits entropy" more or less means "there are only 2<sup>40</sup> possible values for the seed or internal PRNG state". Take note that in the synthetic description above, the conversion from seed to generated private key is completely deterministic. Thus, an attacker can generate all these 2<sup>40</sup> states, and, for each of them, work out the private key that your application would have come up with, starting with that seed value. It then suffices for the attacker to check these keys against your public key (which is public, as the name says) to learn your private key. And impersonate you. Which is bad.

This [actually happened in Debian in 2008](https://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2008/05/random_number_b.html) and people had to regenerate new SSH keys (both client and server).

Comment: They were relying on uninitialized data for security? They don't know how much entropy that had, and it could be zero.

Comment: @immibis They weren't _relying_ on it. They thought it was a cute idea &mdash; at best, it would add some entropy; at worst, it would add nothing. Harmless. The harm came when the code was changed again, inadvertently breaking everything.

Comment: @MattNordhoff If I'm understanding correctly, the harm came from removing the code that used uninitialized data as randomness. That implies the system was relying on that uninitialized data for randomness. Otherwise, removing it wouldn't break things.

Comment: @immibis Removing that line of code was harmless. The problem was they also removed a _separate, but identical_ line of code, unaware _it_ was critically important.

Answer (score 5):

The 2012 paper: [Mining Your Ps and Qs: Detection of Widespread Weak Keys in Network Devices](https://factorable.net/weakkeys12.extended.pdf).

In this case the RNG itself was ok, but poor (ie predictable) entropy was used to seed it. The abstract opens:

> RSA and DSA can fail catastrophically when used with malfunctioning random number generators.

So that seems to fit your question. The authors did a survey of SSL/TLS servers on the open internet and found that

> 0.75% of TLS certificates share keys due to insufficient entropy during key generation, ... Even more alarmingly, we are able to obtain
>   RSA private keys for 0.50% of TLS hosts and 0.03% of
>   SSH hosts, because their public keys shared nontrivial
>   common factors due to entropy problems, and DSA private
>   keys for 1.03% of SSH hosts, because of insufficient
>   signature randomness.

Their guess is that most of these vulnerable devices are headless embedded devices that are generating keys on first boot using basically only the entropy (seed values) they came out of the factory with.

Comment: Do you happen to know whether any institutions having interest in security issues of the Internet have reacted to the paper you cited? (Or even to a paper of A.. K. Lenstra et al. cited in it?)

Comment: @Mok-KongShen Sorry, I have no idea :-(